# How do you group the elements of a stream using keys present in the same stream?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

So I have the following type:

```
case class Episode(
  parentTconst: String,
  seasonNumber: Int,
  episodeNumber: Int
)
```

And the following Source:

```
val episodeSource: Source[Episode, _] = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(myDataFilePath)).via(myDataParserToEpisode)
```

An example list of Episode would be:

```
Seq(
  Episode("gameof", 5, 8),
  Episode("mentalist", 2, 4),
  Episode("gameof", 5, 8),
  Episode("mentalist", 1, 8),
  Episode("rikiandmanual", 1, 8)
)
```

I am trying to make the following Flow (I am not certain that it's the right signature, please advice, maybe it's a Sink since I am consuming the whole stream to get the Map):

```
def gimmeThoseEpisodeGroups: Flow[Episode, Map[String, Seq[Episode]], _]
```

Which would look like this if printed:

```
Map(
  "gameof"        -> Seq(Episode("gameof", 5, 8), Episode("gameof", 5, 8)),
  "mentalist"     -> Seq(Episode("mentalist", 2, 4), Episode("mentalist", 1, 8)),
  "rikiandmanual" -> Seq(Episode("rikiandmanual", 1, 8))
)
```

I tried so many combinaison that didn't work. Maybe the approach is not right.

I think I should use groupBy.
The other thing is maybe I need to consume the stream a first time to get the list of keys for the groups (or maybe find a way to consume it once but producing two results).

I DuckDucked and found out about broadcast, but I have yet to wrap my mind around it.

```scala
    def getGroupedByParentTConst: Flow[Episode, Map[String, Seq[Episode]], _] = Flow[Episode].groupBy(2, _.parentTconst)
```

But that fails (anyways, I have a feeling it's not the right path.

Also, I figured I would extract the parentTconst to use them a grouping keys:

```scala
    def getParentTConst: Flow[Episode, Set[String], _] = Flow[Episode].fold(Set.empty[String]) {
      (right, left) => { right ++ Set(left.parentTconst) }
    }
```

That works, But I am stuck figuring out how to use them to group my original source...

Also, if I use the list of keys, that means, I'll have to consume two streams to get my grouping.

I think I have a Duck problem, it's not a really hard problem, but since I have the constraint of using akka-streams, it's not really straightforward.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The expected type is wrong. `Flow[Episode, Map[String, Seq[Episode]], _]` means each `Episode` will be converted into a `Map[String, Seq[Episode]]`, rather than batch and aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve cannot be done in a streaming fashion, as creating a map of all the grouped episodes requires to read all the data in memory. There isn't any intermediate result.

If you still want to do that you can use fold in a similar fashion to what you where proposing

```
Flow[Episode].fold(Map.empty[String, List[Episode]]) { (map, e) ⇒
  val key = e.parentTconst
  map + (key → v :: map.getOrElse(key, Nil))
}
```

But since that will be reading all the file in memory you may as well save the hassle of using akka-streams and just use `scala.io.Source`.

If you have so much data that you can't fit in memory, then you need to change the requirement.